# Cookies disable in flutter_inappwebview for iOS

Tags: swift, flutter, webview

I am using webview for payment gateway for one of my client.
flutter_inappwebview 4.0.0+4

It is working perfectly for android in this plugin but when I run on iOS it is not working. Payment gateway error shows that cookies are disable in your browswer.

Here is the code.

body: InAppWebView(
initialUrl: weburl,
initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(

```
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        sharedCookiesEnabled: true,
      ),

      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        debuggingEnabled: true,
        javaScriptEnabled: true,

      )
  ),
  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
    webView = controller;

  },
  onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
    if (url == successURL) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/NormalOrderSuccess',
          arguments: RouteArgument(
              heroTag: widget.routeArgument.heroTag, param: order));
    } else if (url == failURL) {
        Payment payment = order.payment;
        payment.status = 'fail';
        order.payment = payment;
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(
            '/NormalOrderSuccess',
            arguments: RouteArgument(
                heroTag: widget.routeArgument.heroTag, param: order));
    }

  },
  onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
    List<Cookie> cookies = await _cookieManager.getCookies(url: url);
    cookies.forEach((cookie) {
      print(cookie.name + " " + cookie.value);
    });
  },
  onProgressChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {

  },
),
```

)),
);

Is there any permission i need to add? If yes then where?

Thanks

Comment: Check the first point under [usage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview#usage).

Comment: I have made that change,. It does not work in safari also if setting "Website Track - Prevent Website tracking" is enabled. If i disable than it works in safari. So how can i disable that settings in this flutter_inappwebview

Comment: Did you got any solution for this ?

Comment: @MayuriRuparel any solution ?